# Exposing Surrogate Key to Users

Tags: database, nhibernate, architecture, orm, primary-key

I'm designing a new application, and there is a table with items that the users would like to uniquely identify with a number.  This table will have a surrogate key, which can be used for this purpose, however I'm undecided if I should expose it to the users.  They will only use this id as read-only and look-ups, and the application will handle the creation of the key behind the scenes.

The idea is to avoid potential problems down the road.  If the key is an identity field, auto generated by the dbms, then you don't have control over the key. I'm using NHibernate in my application, so I can have control over the key by using HiLo, as described [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx), which I intend to use.  In case it matters, the DBMS is Oracle.

What are some of the potential issues I could encounter down the road by exposing the key?

1. Let's assume the users build a dependency on it by making some excel spreadsheets that use this key.  Could the key ever change?
2. If some records get lost in a database corruption or accident, and I want to avoid conflicts with old keys, couldn't I just adjust my starting point in NHibernate to skip the previously generated numbers?
3. What if the users want to change to some other methodology of identifying their records.  Let's say they want to start off with some meaningful character codes.  Could I not then, either show them a computed (not stored) identifier, or create a new alternate key column at any time that is based on my surrogate primary key?

If someone can demonstrate a clear example of how exposing a managed surrogate primary key to user may become a problem down the road I will create an alternate key to present to the users, otherwise I will expose the surrogate primary key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ids are usually and typically should be an implementation concern and users shouldn't care about them.  i suggest you rethink whether showing an identifier to users is really a requirement.  not knowing your specific case, maybe it is, but i doubt it.  users shouldn't care about updating record 12345 or that they are customer 54321.  users should just know that i'm updating my address or buying a specific item.

if exposing the identifier to users is really just having it appear in the querystring, then using the surrogate primary key is completely appropriate.

if it really is a business requirement that the user needs to see the id:

1. the key does not ever have to change and it shouldn't ever change.  catcall's example of being acquired and merging this information into another database is an edge case that probably doesn't happen even in an acquisition and there are other ways around it outside of changing the id like using separate tables or creating a composite key.  i wouldn't worry about that.
2. yes, either way - identity or hilo - you can change the identity seed or update the hibernate_unique_key table to update the range for your new ids.  i'd recommend that in using nhibernate you never use identity and always favor hilo (or guid).  the identity generator requires going to the database to get the id and is in contrast to the way nhibernate likes to work with batching up the operations in the session and going to the database on flush.  some things don't work as well with nhibernate and you'll see subtle and unexpected bugs if you use identity because nhibernate does some things differently than you'd expect in that case (and a few things just don't work).
3. yes, those are certainly options.

i don't think it's a problem to expose the id except that it's probably not really what the user wants in almost all cases.  no technical reason not to, though.

Comment: "rethink whether showing an identifier to users is really a requirement" Showing *an* identifier to users surely is a requirement in most cases. I think the question here is *what* key to use.

Comment: @dportas - if you are talking about showing some natural key then you probably often are showing that as a requirement - not because it is an identifier, but because it is interesting information.  if you are talking about showing a surrogate key that is really some meaningless number (or guid) to the user, i still argue that in almost all cases they don't (ok, shouldn't) care about it.  i'm just asserting that if business users are asking for a meaningless number, it is probably because we've trained them that ids are how things are implemented, not because that's what they really want.

Comment: @Dave - I'm with you, but what are you suggesting for unique item identification?  Users asking for a 'meaningless number' right now because they don't see anything better to suit their needs.

Comment: it depends on your domain.  and it depends on what the users really want.  @dportas has a point in that an application that presents options and allows selection has some identifying information associated with those things.  maybe it's a book title or product name or something like that that is what a user really thinks about when identifying an entity from the domain.  if a user wants to be able to identify something, it's seldom with a surrogate key.  users can learn that to deal with a system they need to deal with a number, but it's not how they view the business.

Comment: i would think users, in general, are interested in identifying items the way they think about them (which may not be universally unique (like a name), but good enough for them to decide in a context what they want).  showing them a contrived number is rarely what they really want.

Comment: @Dave - Book titles are not guaranteed to be unique.  ISBN numbers are unique, but then that is one weird number, and it's not convenient for doing quick look-ups. My users want to have an ID to do quick look-ups with.  There is no unique identifier for the item now.  The surrogate key fits the bill.  How am I to tell them they don't know what they want when I can't offer anything better?

Comment: if that's really what they want, ultimately that's what you deliver. if you don't have a better answer.  i just think you're best off and you're serving them best if you really try to think with them about if that is what they are after.  if they're constructing spreadsheets to try to track things in the system and need ids for that, maybe that's a sign they need something more from the system than what they are getting.  maybe you don't have the resources to provide them with whatever that gap is and hence they are basically implementing it on their own (in excel).

Comment: ideally, i wouldn't want users to have to worry about guarantees on uniqueness.  they are looking for something and find the (maybe book title) they are looking for and have some other context to decide if this is really the right item.  also, it's a bit presumptuous of me to be making the blanket statements i am without really knowing anything about your problem domain.  my goal is not to convince you not to surface the id, but the hope that you are really thinking about and trying to get to the base of user intent.  that's the mark of a truly exceptional technical person.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first three questions are easy

1. No not easily. This is the main benefit of surrogate keys. Candidate Keys that can changes can cause trouble when they're a Primary key.
2. Yes but you shouldn't because of #1
3. Yes and you should.

This one is tougher.

> If someone can demonstrate a clear example of how exposing a managed
>   surrogate primary key to user may become a problem down the road I
>   will create an alternate key to present to the users, otherwise I will
>   expose the surrogate primary key.

But there are two common problems.

1. Users get used to seeing the number increment without holes. But sooner or later they'll get one or many, and they'll ask to get those holes filled. They're aren't many good reasons for this and you need to push-back on that.
2. If your system allows for lookups by ID or worse data entry via ID you can have problems. This is because typos with numbers are very easy. Credit card numbers use Hamming functions to make it hard to mistype a credit card number that is a valid number for this very reason.

So if you make sure you users don't take advantage of the sequential nature of the Surrogate Key and you don't use it for user data input then you should be fine, otherwise you might want to consider using a key generation where you can detect typos.

Comment: Disallowing references by ID seems to defeat the stated purpose of the surrogate ID.

Comment: Well I don't mean to "disallow" them but there does exist predictable problems, with standard solutions. If the stakeholders want to go a different way then more power to them.

Answer (score 1):

Can a surrogate key ever change? Yes. Let's say your company gets bought by another company, and they decide to merge databases. If somebody's id numbers have to change, it will be yours, not theirs. I've been involved in two such system consolidations, and it's *not* pretty.

Although I haven't done it, I believe you can change the starting point in NHibernate. (In most ORMs, you can at the very least create your own class, extending the ORM's class. Then code the behavior you want.)

Can you show users a computed key based on your id number? Not in the general case. When users come up with ideas for keys, they're usually not very good, and almost always require some manual adjustment. So you'd almost certainly have to store it. Nothing wrong with that. (Except in letting users design keys with encoded meaning.)

> If . . . exposing a managed surrogate primary key to user may become a
>   problem down the road I will create an alternate key to present to the
>   users, otherwise I will expose the surrogate primary key.

- Users have to be able to identify things.
- SQL databases use keys to identify things.
- To identify things in a SQL database, users need to see at least one
  natural key.

(There are exceptions, but not many.)

So if you use a hidden surrogate key, you need at least one more natural key to present to the users. Why a natural key? Without one, you risk ending up with tables built like this.

```
id    title
--
1     An Introduction to Database Systems
2     An Introduction to Database Systems
3     An Introduction to Database Systems
4     An Introduction to Database Systems
8     An Introduction to Database Systems
15    An Introduction to Database Systems
37    An Introduction to Database Systems
```

But by hiding the surrogate, the user sees this.

```
title
--
An Introduction to Database Systems
An Introduction to Database Systems
An Introduction to Database Systems
An Introduction to Database Systems
An Introduction to Database Systems
An Introduction to Database Systems
An Introduction to Database Systems
```

If rows related to one of those titles need to be updated, how will users know which title to select?

Comment: In the database merge scenario you describe - sounds like that can be handled by item 3 in my original question, or as Dave describes below http://stackoverflow.com/a/8310521/265877

Answer (score 1):

If users are expected to update individual tuples accurately then they will need a key by which they can identify the information of interest to them. This is normally what is called a business key. A surrogate key is one which has no business meaning and usually that means it isn't exposed to users (otherwise it acquires meaning within the business domain).

It is of course sensible to make sure the users see at least one key for each table. Not a "surrogate" key though. If a key is used for identifying information as part of the business process then it isn't truly a surrogate key and there's not much point in calling it such.

All keys can and do have reasons to change and that includes surrogates.

Comment: So, if I show the surrogate key to the users then I should call it a business key.  Functionally nothing is different, but is it OK to do now?

Comment: Functionally it makes a big difference. Where does this key fit into the business process? You say that users need an "ID to do quick look-ups" but where is the "ID" originating from in such an interaction? An arbitrary number they have never seen before is no use at all for that. The way to determine or design business identifiers is by analysing and understanding the business requirement. It seems like you have some busines analysis to do. Also ask yourself why the surrogate was created in the first place. If you want to do without one then that might be an important consideration too.

Comment: The users are creating new items that don't have an identifier.  They want a simple id to look up the items on.  How am I/they suppose to analyze that differently? The users and I have determined that we need exactly what the surrogate key offers.  Now, I can make another column that is similar to the surrogate key, but what's the point of duplicating an ID column at this stage? What is a clear example of a pitfall of using the surrogate key for user look-ups?  That is my question.

Comment: "User look-ups" doesn't explain much about what they are actually doing. Perhaps what you mean is: "the key will be recorded elsewhere, be used in some part of the business process and therefore the user will need to find data in the table based on that key". That's not a surrogate key. No problem so far. So the question is do you need a surrogate key for this table at all? Probably not. Surrogates are optional and redundant almost by definition. Don't use a surrogate without good reason to do so.

Comment: Gotcha.  What I mean by look-ups is one user telling another user to look up record id 123 on their computer.  They have no requirement for recording somewhere else, although there's nothing preventing them from doing so.  Bottom line, if I don't expose it to the users - it's a surrogate key.  If I do expose it to the users - it's a business key, and I don't really need another surrogate key.  Thanks.

Comment: They will record it somewhere else. If it's used in the way you described then sooner or later it will be written down on post-it notes, in emails, in documentation. So it acquires business meaning. Thst's the essential difference. That's also why designing *good* keys is a science and art of its own. Arbitrary numbers don't necessarily make good keys because they aren't familiar or easy to recognise, remember or enter correctly. They are better than nothing though.

Comment: Thanks.  I've assigned the answer to Dave, since he has less points :)  His help has been as good as yours and, if I could, I would split the answer between you both (and Conrad)